# I was trying to install a program did not work. Now YUM is not working I am getting this message

Tags: installation, centos-7

I am getting this message after tried installing a program. Now Yum is broken

```
 [root@localhost bin]# yum update
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

  -bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I changed the first line yum file in `/usr/bin` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` now yum seems to working. Now trying to check the python version `[root@localhost bin]# python2 --version I am getting this Python 2.7.5`

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/python` present?

Comment: I can find it  `/usr/bin`
python2
python2.7

Comment: I changed the first line `yum` file in `/usr/bin` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` now yum seems to working.